# タグ申請: 特定のタグが登録できない (http の複数形が https？)

Tags: サポート

最近タグ職人に転職できないか悩んでいます。

先日、投稿の編集のついでに、新規タグを追加しようとしていましたところ、どうしても編集できないタグに遭遇しました。どうしようもないので、追加・修正依頼をいたします。二つあります。

#### 1. 複数形 (plural) の扱いで二重登録になるらしいもの

問題のタグは "*https*" で、以下のような警告が発生します。

> タグ [https] を作成しようとしていますが、タグ [http] はすでに存在します!この新しいタグの許可が必要な場合は、メタで取り上げてください。

"*https*" はおそらく必須のタグだと思いますので、追加のご検討をお願いします。この警告機能が要るのかというところもありますが・・・

#### 2. ハイフン (hyphen) の扱いで二重登録になるらしいもの

間違えて "*ef-code-first*" とするべきタグを "*ef-codefirst*" と登録してしまいました。こちらは

> タグ [ef-code-first] を作成しようとしていますが、タグ [ef-codefirst] はすでに存在します!この新しいタグの許可が必要な場合は、メタで取り上げてください。

となり、正しいタグの登録ができない状態ですので、どなたかできれば命名変更をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

タグの追加、及び修正を行いました。ef-codefirstに関しては変更出来なかったので、新しく作成しシノニムにしました。